# Knit Rnw File into PDF and view in Emacs using polymode

Tags: r, emacs, compilation, knitr, ess

I am trying using emacs recently. How can I compile my ".Rnw" file into PDF and view it after the compilation is completed. If I can pass the current file in an express `knit2pdf()`, it will compile. But I have no idea how to do it with subsequent action of viewing PDF.

It would be a lot better if I can compile the main document if I compile from a child `rnw` file.

Answer (score 0):

Install [rnw2pdf](https://github.com/AntonioFasano/rnw2pdf),

```
(require 'rnw2pdf)
```

in your init, then just `M-x rnw2pdf` in your Rnw buffer.

**Note**. Since the command opens the PDF for you, you may want to set in your init:

```
(setq rnw2pdf-viewer "/path/to/pdf-viewer")
```